# Swipte to Refresh keeps adding TextViews

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on an Android app that uses information form an API and displays it in a list view. It works, but I can't figure out how to implement Swipe to Refresh properly. Right now when it refreshes it doesnt update the data in the lists TextView fields, but adds more of them underneath. I'm very new to this and would appreciate help figuring it out.

Here is the code I have so far.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> coinList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> priceList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Swipe Refresh tests

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        swipeView.setEnabled(false);

        ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.list);
        lView.setAdapter(adp);


        swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                        ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                        }, 1000);

                        new GetStats().execute();
                    }
                });

        lView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem == 0)
                    swipeView.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    swipeView.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        ///// END OF SWIPE REFRESH TEST CODE ////



        coinList = new ArrayList<>();
        priceList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);                    // Needs to be here seemingly!!

        new GetStats().execute();
    }


    // Async task class to get JSON over HTTP call

    private class GetStats extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Progress Dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // URL request and response
            String url = "URL";
            String url2 = "URL";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            String jsonStr2 = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url2: " + jsonStr2);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {                                                                                   /// BEGINNING of Parsing Try
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Get JSON Object "getuserallbalances"
                    JSONObject userBalances = jsonObj.getJSONObject("getuserallbalances");

                    // Get JSON Array "data"
                    JSONArray data = userBalances.getJSONArray("data");

                    // Loop through all data
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject d = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        String coin = d.getString("coin");
                        String confirmed = d.getString("confirmed");
                        String unconfirmed = d.getString("unconfirmed");
                        String aeConfirmed = d.getString("ae_confirmed");
                        String aeUnconfirmed = d.getString("ae_unconfirmed");
                        String exchange = d.getString("exchange");

                        //Convert to BigDecimal
                        BigDecimal dConfirmed = new BigDecimal(confirmed);
                        BigDecimal dUnconfirmed = new BigDecimal(unconfirmed);
                        BigDecimal dAeConfirmed = new BigDecimal(aeConfirmed);
                        BigDecimal dAeUnconfirmed = new BigDecimal(aeUnconfirmed);
                        BigDecimal dExchange = new BigDecimal(exchange);

                        // Temp HashMap for single coin
                        HashMap<String, String> coins = new HashMap<>();

                        // Add each child node to HashMap key => value
                        coins.put("coin", coin.toUpperCase());
                        coins.put("confirmed", "Confirmed: " + dConfirmed);
                        coins.put("exchange", "Exchange: " + dExchange);
                        coins.put("unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed: " + dUnconfirmed);
                        coins.put("ae_confirmed", "AE Confirmed: " + dAeConfirmed);
                        coins.put("ae_unconfirmed", "AE Unconfirmed: " + dAeUnconfirmed);

                        // Add to list
                        coinList.add(coins);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {                                                       /// END of Parsing TRY
                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get JSON from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get JSON from server. Check LogCat!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }


            // Second API call (CoinMarketCap)
            if (jsonStr2 != null) {
                try {                                                                                   /// BEGINNING of Parsing Try
                    // Get JSON Array
                    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr2);



                    // Loop through all data
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject p = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = p.getString("id");
                        String price_usd = p.getString("price_usd");

                        // Temp HashMap for single coin
                        HashMap<String, String> prices = new HashMap<>();

                        // Add each child node to HashMap key => value
                        prices.put("id", id.toUpperCase());
                        prices.put("perice_usd", price_usd);


                        // Add to list
                        priceList.add(prices);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {                                                       /// END of Parsing TRY
                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get JSON from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get JSON from server. Check LogCat!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            // Update parsed JSON into ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, coinList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"coin", "confirmed",
                    "exchange", "unconfirmed", "ae_confirmed", "ae_unconfirmed"}, new int[]{R.id.coin,
                    R.id.confirmed, R.id.exchange, R.id.unconfirmed, R.id.ae_confirmed, R.id.ae_unconfirmed});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this makes some sense and would really apreciate any help! If I can get that working, I will probably have more questions, but right now one thing at a time. :P

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your swipe refresh listener when you call your async task, your are creating a new adapter every time. simply call notifyDataChanged on your data.

In your on background task first check if the data is already present in your priceList then don't add the item in your list.

Or you can first clear the list and then add all the result from json in to price list.

Here is the code which clears list on swipe refresh:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> coinList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> priceList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Swipe Refresh tests

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        swipeView.setEnabled(false);

        ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, coinList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"coin", "confirmed",
                    "exchange", "unconfirmed", "ae_confirmed", "ae_unconfirmed"}, new int[]{R.id.coin,
                    R.id.confirmed, R.id.exchange, R.id.unconfirmed, R.id.ae_confirmed, R.id.ae_unconfirmed});
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);


        swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                        ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                        }, 1000);

                        new GetStats().execute();
                    }
                });

        lView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem == 0)
                    swipeView.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    swipeView.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        ///// END OF SWIPE REFRESH TEST CODE ////



        coinList = new ArrayList<>();
        priceList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);                    // Needs to be here seemingly!!

        new GetStats().execute();
    }


    // Async task class to get JSON over HTTP call

    private class GetStats extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Progress Dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // URL request and response
            String url = "https://miningpoolhub.com/index.php?page=api&action=getuserallbalances&api_key=MyApiKey";
            String url2 = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            String jsonStr2 = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url2: " + jsonStr2);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try { 
                    coinList.clear();                                                                                  /// BEGINNING of Parsing Try
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Get JSON Object "getuserallbalances"
                    JSONObject userBalances = jsonObj.getJSONObject("getuserallbalances");

                    // Get JSON Array "data"
                    JSONArray data = userBalances.getJSONArray("data");

                    // Loop through all data
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject d = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        String coin = d.getString("coin");
                        String confirmed = d.getString("confirmed");
                        String unconfirmed = d.getString("unconfirmed");
                        String aeConfirmed = d.getString("ae_confirmed");
                        String aeUnconfirmed = d.getString("ae_unconfirmed");
                        String exchange = d.getString("exchange");

                        //Convert to BigDecimal
                        BigDecimal dConfirmed = new BigDecimal(confirmed);
                        BigDecimal dUnconfirmed = new BigDecimal(unconfirmed);
                        BigDecimal dAeConfirmed = new BigDecimal(aeConfirmed);
                        BigDecimal dAeUnconfirmed = new BigDecimal(aeUnconfirmed);
                        BigDecimal dExchange = new BigDecimal(exchange);

                        // Temp HashMap for single coin
                        HashMap<String, String> coins = new HashMap<>();

                        // Add each child node to HashMap key => value
                        coins.put("coin", coin.toUpperCase());
                        coins.put("confirmed", "Confirmed: " + dConfirmed);
                        coins.put("exchange", "Exchange: " + dExchange);
                        coins.put("unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed: " + dUnconfirmed);
                        coins.put("ae_confirmed", "AE Confirmed: " + dAeConfirmed);
                        coins.put("ae_unconfirmed", "AE Unconfirmed: " + dAeUnconfirmed);
                        Coin coinObj= new Coin(/*pass the arguments*/);
                        // Add to list
                        coinList.add(coins);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {                                                       /// END of Parsing TRY
                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get JSON from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get JSON from server. Check LogCat!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }


            // Second API call (CoinMarketCap)
            if (jsonStr2 != null) {
                try {
                    priceList.clear();                                                                                   /// BEGINNING of Parsing Try
                    // Get JSON Array
                    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr2);



                    // Loop through all data
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject p = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = p.getString("id");
                        String price_usd = p.getString("price_usd");

                        // Temp HashMap for single coin
                        HashMap<String, String> prices = new HashMap<>();

                        // Add each child node to HashMap key => value
                        prices.put("id", id.toUpperCase());
                        prices.put("perice_usd", price_usd);


                        // Add to list
                        priceList.add(prices);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {                                                       /// END of Parsing TRY
                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get JSON from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get JSON from server. Check LogCat!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            // Update parsed JSON into ListView
            // ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            //         MainActivity.this, coinList,
            //         R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"coin", "confirmed",
            //         "exchange", "unconfirmed", "ae_confirmed", "ae_unconfirmed"}, new int[]{R.id.coin,
            //         R.id.confirmed, R.id.exchange, R.id.unconfirmed, R.id.ae_confirmed, R.id.ae_unconfirmed});

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance of an example how to do that? Which bits doI have to chang? As I said, my understanding is somewhat lacking as I'm very new to all this.

Comment: there will be couple of changes in your code. I will add code after some time

Comment: Thank you! I would appreciate that a lot! :)

Comment: also in the mean time have a look at recycler view which gives you alot of flexibility how to structure your data which is used by view. currently with ArrayAdapter and List view you are limited to use hashmap structure

Comment: see my updated answer which now clears the list and load new data.

Comment: Thanks for that! :) Just one little problem - I'm getting 'Cannot resolve method 'notifyDataSetChanged()' in the onPostExecute(). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Matt should call that function using adapter object

Comment: @Matt and dont share you api urls to such forums .. just "url" would be easily understandable by dev community

Comment: @Adeel Turk those api urls are completly public. I removed the personal  info, but you are right - could just do URL and clean the post up a bit.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly 'notifyDataSetChanged()' does not work with SimpleAdapter, is that right? So any suggestions how to fix?

Comment: Then may be you have to use custom adapter or other adapter provided in  Android which supports data change notify

Comment: Or you could just use your implementation and simply call coinList.clear before looping the json array

Comment: @UmarHussain Thank you! the coinList.clear() seems to have worked, much appreciated :)

Comment: You welcome, please mark the answer correct as well to help others who see your question